# Serving python CGI script with Apache2

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I'm trying to call a Python script from a webpage, and apache2 is not actioning the script.  The files are:

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="./test.py" method="POST">
    <input type="text" size="70" name="data" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

I've enabled `a2enmod cgi` and edited apache settings as follows:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
<directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    Require all granted
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Webpage files ownerships are:

```
# ls -lh /var/www/html/
total 16K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  342 May 30 13:34 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   88 May 30 14:11 test.py
```

Running `apachectl -M` brings up a list with line `cgid_module (shared)`.

When I bring up the page I can see the form, but when I click 'Submit' the browser either prompts to download `test.py` (FF) or views it (Chrome).  Any idea what I'm getting wrong here?

Comment: A good way to check if your meta info tag works is to use `Ctrl+Shift+J` and check the network tab and the returned content-type of your py script. What does chrome say you're getting, text/plain file? I'm guessing you've reloaded the servers configuration?

Comment: Screen shots for what you ask in Chrome and FF - http://imgur.com/a/lGkN5

Comment: I'm on the phone so can't write a proper answer yet. Your mime info is wrong, the content-type for your py file is `document` and there for py script isn't registered as a handler. Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html for now

Comment: Also are you sure you placed the file under `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`? What does apache say in the logs? Just to be clear changing the mime type manually won't make the script execute, just to show you why you're getting document :)

Comment: Ah that's it!  I needed to point `<directory..>` to `/var/www/html`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments. This directory configuration looks like a plain copy from an example, and your Web root is probably somewhere else.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <directory "/var/www/htdocs">
        AllowOverride None Options
        +ExecCGI -MultiViews 
        +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all 
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
        Require all granted
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For instance where directory is changed. That's the default path usually, if yours is `/var/www/html` change accordingly.

I've gotten shit for this earlier but this question might also be better off on [serverfault](https://serverfault.stackexchange.com) considering this is strictly related to how apache should be configured.

Comment: Thanks Torxed. I agree serverfault is ideally better, but I was persuaded by the 3X more apache posts in SO..

Comment: @geotheory i was too at first, but I'm trying to get a more frequent user base there so the searches related to server stuff ends up there hehe. Glad it worked out this time tho :) and you're more than welcome!